# PHP to execute python code not working if ther is import in python

Tags: python, php

I am executing python code in PHP, the python scripts works fine in cmd line, but does not display anything when running in PHP.

```
<?php

echo "<h1>Robot Trading Testing</h1>";

echo '<form method="post">';

echo '<input type="text" name="startdate" placeholder="Start Date" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="enddate" placeholder="End Date" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="currency" placeholder="Currency" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="frequency" placeholder="Frequency" />';

echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
echo '</form>' ;

echo '<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the server called "action_page.php".</p>';

// Check if the form is submitted 
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) 
{ 
    // retrieve the form data by using the element's name attributes value as key 
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate']; 
    $currency = $_POST['currency']; 
    $frequency = $_POST['frequency']; 

    // display the results
    echo '<h3>data input are</h3>'; 
    echo $startdate . ' ' . $enddate . ' ' . $currency . ' ' . $frequency; 

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    $output = shell_exec("usr/bin/doc/python helloworld.py");
    echo '<h3>python file executed, output is: </h3>';  
    echo $output;


    exit; 
} 

?>
```

helloworld.py is as below:

```
import sys
import pandas

print('Hello World')
```

but if I remove "import pandas" from helloworld.py, it is working.

I am using windows, python3.6

Cannot figure out why PHP cannot execute python script when import python packages other than sys.

Thank you.

Comment: Because the user account under which your code is running doesn't have [it's `PYTHONPATH` env var](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) correctly set. And you shouldn't harcode the python's bin path either FWIW.

Comment: I just configured Apache httpd.conf file, and run from local server for the updated helloworld.py directly, but got erro 500 ```#!C:/Users/myname/Anaconda3/python.exe 

import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import pandas


print('Hello World')```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I just updated index.php to ```$output = shell_exec("python helloworld.py");```, and add ```#!C:/Users/myname/Anaconda3/python.exe``` to helloworld.py, but still not working, could you please let me know what's the right way to set env var here? thank you very much!

Comment: Adding a shebang to your python script is just as bad as hardcoding your python bin path in the PHP code. You want to provide this path in the env of the process that executes your PHP code, not in Python. Same for the PYTHONPATH. Those are pretty standard apache config stuff and are documented.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you, I am new to Apache, I just removed shebang, and set system environment variables to ```C:\Python3.6\``` , but still not working, anywhere in Apache httpd.conf I need to add something like ```PythonHome C:/Python3.6```? If yes, where to add? and do I need to add ```LoadFile C:/Python3.6/libs/python36.lib``` to somewhere? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry but those are not programming question, those are server configuration ones (even if PYTHONPATH is python-specific, it's still just an env var).